# Get whereBetween on the lowest relationship table column

Tags: php, laravel, request, product

I've got some product with deals. Every product has several deals. I managed to get the whereBetween, but only on all associated deals. I would like to only return products where the lowest deal matches the whereBetween.

So get products where the lowest associated deal price is between the min & max given price.

Here is my code so far:

```
$products = Product::when($request->filled('brand'), function ($query)use($request) {
    $brandRequest = $request->input('brand');
    $brandReqArray = explode(',', $brandRequest);
    $query->whereHas('brands', function($q) use ($brandReqArray)  {
        $q->whereIn('slug', $brandReqArray);
    });
})->when($request->filled('gender'), function ($query)use($request) {
    $genderRequest = $request->input('gender');
    $genderReqArray = explode(',', $genderRequest);
    $query->whereHas('genders', function($q) use ($genderReqArray)  {
        $q->whereIn('slug', $genderReqArray);
    });
})->when($request->filled('price'), function ($query)use($request) {
    $priceRequest = $request->input('price');
    $priceReqArray = explode(';', $priceRequest);
    $query->whereHas('deals', function($q) use ($priceReqArray)  {
        $q->whereBetween('price', $priceReqArray);
    }); 
})->with(['deals'  => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('price','asc');
}])->paginate(24);

$input = $request->only(['brands', 'gender', 'price']);
$products->appends($input);
```

Comment: you question is not clear mate, do you want to get only the products which has deals in the price range, if its has no deal in the range you want to skip the particular product , is it? or something else?

Comment: Sorry! I want to get only the products where the lowest deal->price is in the price range. So every product has several deals and I want to take the lowest deal->price of each product and check if it's in the price range and then return the corresponding products.

Comment: you want to get the products which has deals in the price range, but only lowest deals which comes in that range and not all products in the price range, is it?

Comment: Exactly that! I've been trying a lot but still no success..

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know, is that what you wanted?

```
    $products = Product::when($request->filled('brand'), function ($query)use($request) {
    $brandRequest = $request->input('brand');
    $brandReqArray = explode(',', $brandRequest);
    $query->whereHas('brands', function($q) use ($brandReqArray)  {
        $q->whereIn('slug', $brandReqArray);
    });
})->when($request->filled('gender'), function ($query)use($request) {
    $genderRequest = $request->input('gender');
    $genderReqArray = explode(',', $genderRequest);
    $query->whereHas('genders', function($q) use ($genderReqArray)  {
        $q->whereIn('slug', $genderReqArray);
    });
})->when($request->filled('price'), function ($query)use($request) {
    $priceRequest = $request->input('price');
    $priceReqArray = explode(';', $priceRequest);
    $query->whereHas('deals', function($q) use ($priceReqArray)  {
        $q->whereBetween('price', $priceReqArray)
        ->whereNotExists(function ($q)use($priceReqArray) {
            $q->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('deals')  
                //->whereNull('deals.deleted_at')                     
                ->whereNotBetween('price', $priceReqArray)
            ->whereRaw('product.id = deals.productId');
        }) 
        ->orderBy('price','asc')->limit(1);
    })
})->paginate(24);
```

Comment: Unfortunately already tried this, not working. Still getting the wrong products.

So for example: I've got a product with 3 deals, the lowest deal price is €30 the highest is €60. When filtering in the range of €40 to €60, I'm still getting this product. Hope this helps to get your head around it..

Comment: I have updated my answer, check whether it solves your problem

Comment: Sorry to say man, still getting the wrong products. Only thing now is that it only shows the first deal of the first product that matches the price range. All the other products are showing no price but are still visible.

Comment: again you are confusing me, do you want products only which has deals in the range, and also you want to get 1 deal which has lowest price in the range?

Comment: check my update, i added `take` instead of `limit`, just try and let me know. this query must return you only the products which have deals in the price range and also it will include only one deal which has lower price

Comment: `take` & `limit` are just aliases right? Not working, unfortunately. I want to show the products where the best/lowest deal is in the price range. So the lowest deal->price of Product A is for example €30 but it also has deals->price with values of €50 & €60. The the lowest deal->price of Product B is for example €50. When I check for the price range of €40 till €60 I only want to return product B with the lowest deal->price. Hope this makes a little bit more sense ;)

Comment: if you apply your requirement, I am sure you will also get product A, because it also has one deal in your price range, isn't it?

Comment: Yes but that's exactly the problem, I don't want to return product A because I only want to filter on the lowest deals associated with the product.

Comment: but really you need to be more specific on why you expect to skip product A, your query condition will surely return it, 
since it meets your price range, both product A and B have a deal in your example case., am i wrong?

Comment: No, you're right. But I don't want that to happen. I want to check if the lowest deal (Product A -> 30 & Product B -> 50) of each product is in the price range. If not, don't show/return the product.

Comment: I understand what you wanted, its something non standard query result, anyway I added a filter for you in my code above, hope it should work as you expect,

Comment: please make sure to mention the correct column names for following lines, `->whereRaw('product.id = deals.productId');` and correct table name for `->from('deals')  `, if you want you can check soft delete as well by the commented line `//->whereNull('deals.deleted_at')`

Comment: Thanks Akram! But now it takes the first deal (with the lowest id) in the database of each product and compares it to the price range. Is there a way you can do a "lowest" search in the deal prices and then compare it to the price range?